# Flipping an icon and spinning it in reverse

Tags: html, css, css-animations, font-awesome

There's an icon in the [Font Awesome set](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) that I want to flip horizontally and then spin in that direction, which is the opposite of the regular spin effect.

There are a number of ways to do each, but none that I know that will do both since the effects seem to cancel each other out?

If I flip it,

```
.fa-refresh {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

then animate it,

```
.icon-spin-reverse {
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-animation: spin-reverse 2s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: spin-reverse 2s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: spin-reverse 2s infinite linear;
    animation: spin-reverse 2s infinite linear;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin-reverse {
    0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(-359deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin-reverse {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-359deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes spin-reverse {
    0% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -o-transform: rotate(-359deg); }
}
@-ms-keyframes spin-reverse {
    0% { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -ms-transform: rotate(-359deg); }
}
@keyframes spin-reverse {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(-359deg); }
}
```

the flip will be canceled, and it will just spin in reverse.

Is there any way to do both?

Comment: Missy Elliot might know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `animation` is overriding the initial `transform`. You need to apply both of the `transforms` in your `animation`:

```css
.fa-refresh {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  animation: spin-reverse 2s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes spin-reverse {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(-360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
```

Comment: It's flipped but it's spinning the wrong direction! But `360deg` instead of `-360deg` works, so thanks!

Comment: @Yeats no need to say thank you, accepting the answer is enough to let the author know it was useful.

Comment: @Alagaros Should I accept the answer as is, even though it's slightly wrong, or wait for an edit (can't make it myself)?

Comment: @Yeats Already suggested an edit. You can already accept the answer since it did solve the your general problem, this is just optimizing it.

Answer (score 3):

The simple way to reverse your animation is to reverse the direction of its CSS property called animation-direction.

```
animation-direction: reverse;
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can also solve the problem without additional CSS.**

The outer `<i>` flips the inner `<i>` first. The inner `<i>` spins. See here:

```
<i class="fa fa-flip-vertical">
  <i class="fa fa-spin fa-refresh"></i>
</i>
```