# Flipping an icon HORIZONTALLY and spinning it on VERTICAL axis

Tags: javascript, html, font-awesome

> First of all I would like to address to anyone reading this, that my
>   question seems awfully similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126148/flipping-an-icon-and-spinning-it-in-reverse) that was asked
>   almost a year ago, but rest assured **it is not!**

This is the bit of code I'm trying to work on:

```
TRENDING NOW&#160;
<span class="fa-trending" style="color:#CF4D35;">
<i class="fa fa-fire fa-spin"></i>
</span>
```

**You can see it RUN in the snippet below:**

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />TRENDING NOW&#160;
<span class="fa-trending" style="color:#CF4D35;">
<i class="fa fa-fire fa-spin"></i>
</span>
<!-- NOT THE MAIN CODE BELOW: IGNORE THIS -->
<br/>
<br/><strong>Question:</strong> How do I rotate that flame along the vertical Y-axis so that it flips horizontally at each half-rotation to produce a flickering-flame effect?
<br/>
<br/><strong>Note:</strong> Any out of the box, bright ideas, are also entertained. However, usage of font awesome is preferable as long as it is possible
```

### What am I trying to do?

Instead of the usual spinning motion offered by font awesome, I would like to spin the font along the **vertical axis** i.e. When, say, ◄ makes a half turn, it should look like this ► (and NOT look like this ▼)

> I am actually trying to make a **flickering flame** with font awesome

### Tracing the spin:

If that was confusing, let me trace the desired output

1. initial-state:◄
2. half-rotation:►
3. full-rotation:◄
4. repeat

> I accept any creative ideas that will let me achieve the same result
>   (but **please don't** let the alternate solution affect the page-load
>   time. I'd ideally prefer to keep it font awesome because it is awesome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you want something like this?

**Update:** I thing I got what you are trying to achieve here. I added a fixed border below the fire so that the base looks stationary, which brings out a better effect. And about making things slow do not worry about it because this is purely done with CSS3 animation and no JavaScript required at all. It will run smooth in everything and will not slow things down.

```css
.flicker {
  perspective: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 15px;
  border-bottom: thin solid #CF4D35;
}
.flicker-ver:before {
  -webkit-animation: filckering 2s infinite;
  animation: filckering 2s infinite;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes filckering {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes filckering {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
}
.flicker-hor:before {
  -webkit-animation: filckering2 .2s infinite;
  animation: filckering2 .2s infinite;
  display: inline-block;
}
@-webkit-keyframes filckering2 {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes filckering2 {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />TRENDING NOW&#160;
<span class="fa-trending" style="color:#CF4D35;">
<i class="fa fa-fire flicker flicker-hor"></i>
<!--i class="fa fa-fire flicker flicker-ver"></i-->
</span>
<!-- NOT THE MAIN CODE BELOW: IGNORE THIS -->
<br/>
<br/><strong>Question:</strong> How do I rotate that flame along the vertical Y-axis so that it flips horizontally at each half-rotation to produce a flickering-flame effect?
<br/>
<br/><strong>Note:</strong> Any out of the box, bright ideas, are also entertained. However, usage of font awesome is preferable as long as it is possible
```

Comment: The **first one** is what I was looking for. Although the result is not what I imagined exactly. I wanted a _reflection by rotation_ effect. Maybe I should have been even more clearer with my question. So let me rephrase: Your **first solution** is golden but could you remove the transition so that I can get a gif-like effect? I do not want any transitions because they are actually making things slower. Also, I reckon, that with only 2-frames(in this transition), the update time should be a little slower to give a nice flickering flame effect(as in a gif)

Comment: Please mark it as correct if it gave you a solution.

Comment: Not exactly the flicker effect that I seek, but you have done exceedingly well with what limited description I might have been able to convey. I shall build upon this solution by stacking different colored fonts below it for my purposes. For the time being(and as per the core request of the question), this is as close as it gets, it seems. So I'll gladly mark your answer. Have a good day!

Answer (score 2):

> I've marked the most helpful answer for this question to @Roy . His answer will be useful for all users who are wondering how to achieve *reflection by rotation* effect with font awesome.

For a more hands on - practical answer, I would like to share my own twist to the marked answer. This is done so that the second requirement of the question(**flickering fame effect**) is handled (*this one's for anyone curious in the future*)
Here's my implementation which solved my problem:

```
<span class="fa-trending fa-stack" style="color:#CF4D35; font-size:20px;">
<i class="fa fa-fire flicker flicker-hor fa-stack-2x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-fire flicker flicker-hor2delay fa-stack-1x" style="color:#FFDF9F"></i>
</span>
```

I simply stacked @Roy's solution with another animation and added an **inverse rotation going from Y-360 to Y-0** (*instead of a delay; which I had previously thought I'd use when I saw @Roy's code*)for my purposes. Reason: *Delay made the flame look inconsistent so I used inverse rotation.*

> I recon, there is a inbuilt class in font awesome to simply make inverse starting points. That works too and you can avoid two extra css-classes that way.

You can see it work by viewing the snippet below:

```css
.flicker {
  perspective: 2000px;
  height: 20px;
  /* caution: change this value along with font-size on html for the perfect flame ;) */
  border-bottom: thin solid #CF4D35;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.flicker-hor2delay:before {
  -webkit-animation: filckering .2s infinite;
  animation: filckering .2s infinite;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes filckering {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes filckering {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(3600deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
.flicker-hor:before {
  -webkit-animation: filckering2 .2s infinite;
  animation: filckering2 .2s infinite;
  display: inline-block;
}
@-webkit-keyframes filckering2 {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes filckering2 {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
/*credits to @Roy for the code */
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />TRENDING NOW
<br/>
<span class="fa-trending fa-stack" style="color:#CF4D35; font-size:20px;">
<i class="fa fa-fire flicker flicker-hor fa-stack-2x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-fire flicker flicker-hor2delay fa-stack-1x" style="color:#FFDF9F"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Yes I was able to make this, mostly with your contribution. Although I quickly learnt to apply this particular animation after page onload only(Reason: _It messes up other elements in the page_ due to its irregular properties). When I implemented this to replace an existing fa-icon , it didn't match up properly with others of similar font-size. Hence, I had to load this particular thing after my whole page gets loaded with jQuery. **Implementation:** I loaded the original and then replaced it with this after window loads. Leaving this comment just in-case anyone else faces the same problem ltr